# Converting Leads Error

Tags: apex, lead-conversion

I am trying to convert lead's through asynchronous apex, but I get the following error message:

> System.DmlException: ConvertLead failed. First exception on row 5; first error: DUPLICATES_DETECTED, You're creating a duplicate record. We recommend you use an existing record instead.: []

This is my apex code, where I am checking if the Lead's email already exists in the system as a contact email. I might be doing something wrong:

```
List<ID> ids = new List<ID>();

ids.add('XXXXXXXXX');

List<String> leadEmails = new List<String>();
List<Lead> leads1 = new List<Lead>([Select id,Account__c,email, firstname, lastname  from Lead where id in: ids and isConverted=false  and Account__c !=null]);
for(Lead l: leads1)
    leadEmails.add(l.email);

List<String> contactEmails = new List<String>();
List<Contact> contacts = new List<contact>([Select id,lastname,firstname, email from Contact where email in: leadEmails]);
for(contact c: contacts)
    contactEmails.add(c.email);


List<Lead> leads = new List<Lead>([Select id,Account__c,email, firstname, lastname  from Lead where id in: ids and isConverted=false  and Account__c !=null and email not in: contactEmails]);
system.debug(contactEmails);
system.debug(leads1);

  Database.LeadConvert[] converts = new Database.LeadConvert[0];
    for(Lead record: leads) {

            Database.LeadConvert thisLead = new Database.LeadConvert();
            thisLead.setLeadId(record.Id);
            thisLead.setAccountId(record.Account__c);
            thisLead.setConvertedStatus('Closed - Converted');
            thisLead.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);
            converts.add(thisLead);
        }

    if(!converts.isEmpty()) {
       Database.convertLead(converts);
    }
```

Comment: Are there any duplicate rules in your organization? or is there any field on Account/contact.Opportunity which is marked as unique?

Comment: only the email is unique

Comment: (1) what is the `ids.add('XXXX')` for ?  (2) n.b. `List<Lead> leads1 = new List<Lead>([some soql]);` is overly complex, you can simply do `List<Lead> leads1 = [some soql];`  no list constructor required

Comment: (1) I hard code the lead id's and 'XXXX' was meant to be an example (2) good to know tnx